# Changing css on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this has been discussed before, but I can't seem to get it work for me, I would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to change the opacity of a logo after scrolling some pixels with this code:

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 675 ) {
                $('.logo_full').css('opacity', '1');
            } else {
                $('.logo_full').css('opacity', '0'); 
            }
        });
</script>
```

Here is a live version of the things. I believe it's better to check it out live rather than on some pieces of code. [link](http://thecevadolas.com/novo/)

I'm starting to think that this is some js incompability or some stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: I made a jquery plugin for something like this:https://github.com/DebonairStudios/fromTop.js obviously, i am biased towards it, but it is pretty useful :D

Comment: There is no logo to change opacity on? this is why fiddle is better than full site...

Comment: There is a logo that is currently hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper').scroll(function() {
        if ( $('#wrapper').scrollTop() >= 675 ) {
            $('.logo_full').css('opacity', '1');
        } else {
            $('.logo_full').css('opacity', '0'); 
        }
    });
});
```

$(window).scrollTop() is constantly returning 0, while as you scroll, $('#wrapper').scrollTop() will indeed return the result you are expecting. You may need to wrap it in a $(document).ready to make sure you are binding at the right time.

Comment: I did as you said and the logo is still not turning to opacity 1.
I've already upload it, could you check it out?

Comment: You have $(window).scroll, try $('#wrapper').scroll

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you wanted to get fancy, you can leverage jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut as well. http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: I believe a transition on the css would be much more simple. my opinion tho.